# cordova contacts not working when using it from a separate file

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use the cordova contacts plugin. Here's what I got on the `app.js` file.

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $compileProvider){

 $stateProvider 
  .state('app.contacts', {
    url: "/contacts",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/contacts.html",
        controller: 'ContactsController'
      }
    }
  });

});
```

I also have an `app-starter.js` file which I use to initialize the controllers. This is also where I initialize `ngCordova` which is needed so I can use the cordova contacts plugin:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', ['ngCordova']);
```

Then in the Contacts Controller file I have this:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app.controllers')
    .controller('ContactsController', ['$scope', ContactsController]);

    function ContactsController($scope, $cordovaContacts){

        var me = this;
        me.contacts = [];

        me.fetchContacts = function(){
            alert('now fetching contacts..');
            $cordovaContacts.find({ multiple: true}).then(
                function(results){
                    alert('contacts fetched! heres the first one: ');
                    alert(results[0]['displayName']);
                    me.contacts = results;
                }, 
                function(error){
                    alert('error retrieving contacts');
                }
            );
        };

    };
})();
```

I also have another controller (Main App Controller) which I use for storing methods which I use throughout the app:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app.controllers')
    .controller('AppController', ['$scope', AppController]);

    function AppController($scope){

        var me = this;

        me.alert = function(){
            alert('alert');
        };


    };
})();
```

the `fetchContacts` method basically just listens to a click event. And then it gets the contacts.

Here's the `templates/contacts.html` file:

```
<ion-view view-title="Contacts" ng-controller="ContactsController as contacts_ctrl">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Contacts</h1>
    <button class="button button-positive button-block" ng-click="contacts_ctrl.fetchContacts()">Fetch Contacts</button>
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item" ng-repeat="contact in contacts_ctrl.contacts">{{ contact.displayName }}</li>
    </ul>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And here's my main `index.html` file where I link all the files that I need:

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've already tried a few alternatives such as including `ngCordova` in the `app.js` file:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'app.controllers'])
```

And using the same code I have above for the Contacts Controller.

I also tried putting it in the main App Controller, but it doesn't work either:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app.controllers', ['ngCordova'])
```

Putting it in the Contacts Controller doesn't work either:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app.controllers', ['ngCordova'])
```

The only thing that seems to work is when I put the controller in the `app.js` file:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers'])
.controller(function($scope, $cordovaContacts){

  //same code as Contacts Controller above

});
```

But the problem is I don't really like doing it this way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't passing in `$cordovaContacts` in my controller. So instead of this:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app.controllers')
    .controller('ContactsController', ['$scope', ContactsController]);

    function ContactsController($scope, $cordovaContacts){


    };
})();
```

It should be like this:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app.controllers')
    .controller('ContactsController', ['$scope', '$cordovaContacts', ContactsController]);

    function ContactsController($scope, $cordovaContacts){



    };
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

The code where you add `app.controllers` in the `app.js` works, because you are creating a module called `app.controllers` and in order to use it you have to reference it in the `app.js`. If you replace this code

```
 angular.module('app.controllers')
.controller('ContactsController', ['$scope', ContactsController]);
```

with

```
 angular.module('app')
.controller('ContactsController', ['$scope', ContactsController]);
```

it should work without referencing the `app.controllers`. Otherwise you should reference your module.